# javascript code that is used to show a div modified to work with multiple unique divs

Tags: javascript

I've got a `<select>` form field, and onchange it runs a javascript function.  If the function matches something specific, it shows new form field options located inside of a `<div style="display: none;">`

I've got a unique situation where I need to use this same code across multiple select boxes; however, each one has a specific name.  They are not all the same and need to work independantly.  Each one has a unique ID #.

I only want the second select field to show up if "ship with" is selected in the first field.

First, here is the code for the select field

```
<select name="first_select_option" onchange="ShowDiv(this);">
<option value="">Select Option</option>
<option value="SHIP WITH" id="SHIPWITH_<?php echo $data_order_id; ?>_Show">SHIP WITH</option>';
</select>
```

Here is the code for the hidden select field.  There are multiple of these called dynamically on the page during a php while loop.  That is why I am using the `<?php echo $data_order_id; ?>` inside the id of each one.

```
<div id="SHIPWITH_<?php echo $data_order_id;?>" style="display: none;">
<select name="secondhiddenselect">
<option value="">SELECT OPTIONS BELOW</option>
</select>
</div>
```

As you notice I am using a php variable inside the id.  That is a unique id assigned to that specific select field inside a while loop.  So the more while loops, the more select fields are pupulated, therefore, there end up being a bunch of select fields each with a unique ID all because of the `$data_order_id`

I need to modify the following script to not only work with a single `SHIPWITH`, but work with each individual `SHIP WITH_{id}`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function ShowDiv(nameSelect)
{
    console.log(nameSelect);
    if(nameSelect){
        OptionValue = document.getElementById("NEWCC_Show").value;
        if(OptionValue == nameSelect.value){
            document.getElementById("NEWCC").style.display = "block";
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("NEWCC").style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("NEWCC").style.display = "none";
    }
}
    </script>
```

I attempted to modify this and make it work by using `.split('_')` to break the variable up but its not working.  I am not as good with JavaScript as I'd like to be. Here is my attempt...

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ShowDiv(nameSelect)
{
    console.log(nameSelect);
    if(nameSelect){

        var name = nameSelect;
        var splitName = name.split('_');

        alert(splitName[1]);

        OptionValue = document.getElementById(splitName[0] + splitName[1] + splitName[2]).value;
        if(OptionValue == nameSelect.value){
            document.getElementById(splitName[0] + splitName[1]).style.display = "block";
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById(splitName[0] + splitName[1]).style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById(splitName[0] + splitName[1]).style.display = "none";
    }
}
    </script>
```

So even though there are multiple select fields, the JavaScript ONLY communicates with the specific one that corresponds with the `$data_order_id`.

Here is an updated snippet to help diagnose problem

```js
function ShowDiv(nameSelect) {


  console.log(nameSelect);
  if (nameSelect) {

    var name = nameSelect;
    var splitName = name.split('_');

    alert(splitName[1]);

    OptionValue = document.getElementById(splitName[0] + splitName[1] + splitName[2]).value;
    if (OptionValue == nameSelect.value) {
      document.getElementById(splitName[0] + splitName[1]).style.display = "block";
    } else {
      document.getElementById(splitName[0] + splitName[1]).style.display = "none";
    }
  } else {
    document.getElementById(splitName[0] + splitName[1]).style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<select name="number_of_skids" onchange="ShowDiv(this);">
  <option value="SHIP WITH" id="SHIPWITH_11_Show">SHIP WITH</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2" selected="selected">2</option>
</select>

<div id="SHIPWITH_11" style="display: none;">
  <select name="ship_with_product">
    <option value="">SELECT PRODUCT</option>
    <option value="4">1234</option>
  </select>
</div>


<select name="number_of_skids" onchange="ShowDiv(this);">
  <option value="SHIP WITH" id="SHIPWITH_21_Show">SHIP WITH</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2" selected="selected">2</option>
</select>

<div id="SHIPWITH_21" style="display: none;">
  <select name="ship_with_product">
    <option value="">SELECT PRODUCT</option>
    <option value="4">1234</option>
  </select>
</div>





<select name="number_of_skids" onchange="ShowDiv(this);">
  <option value="SHIP WITH" id="SHIPWITH_33_Show">SHIP WITH</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2" selected="selected">2</option>
</select>

<div id="SHIPWITH_33" style="display: none;">
  <select name="ship_with_product">
    <option value="">SELECT PRODUCT</option>
    <option value="4">1234</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I suggest using CSS classes instead of trying to combine ids like that. Also, `+` is the string concatenation operator in JavaScript, not `.`...

Comment: I am using them like this because I need each one to work independantly.  I don't need for one select box to be able to show ALL of the hiddne fields.  Each select box is tied to one specific hidden field

Comment: I edited the code removing the extra `$` that i forgot to remove and change the code from `.` to `+` and it still isnt working.  ITs actually not even alerting me of the name.  I don't think the `.split` is working at all?

Comment: It's really hard to parse what's going on here. Can you take a sample of the rendered HTML (i.e., not the PHP code), combine it with the code you've got, and put it in a Stack Snippet (icon in the editor looks like `<>`). That would make it significantly easier to help.

Comment: Please modify your question to clearly include the use case with the single select.  Right now, the `ShowDiv` function which presumably is the single select case refers to some "NEWCC_Show" element - which is completely absent from your question.

Comment: You might also want to rethink how you're creating your options.  The "value" attribute is currently redundant (it's identical to the `text` of the option).  You could put the `id` of the appropriate select in the `value` and stop cluttering your namespace with a ton of superfluous `id`s

Comment: the value is used in database storage.  I did that on purpose.  But thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: @HereticMonkey - snippet added with a sample

Comment: I think I misunderstood how this code was wroking until just now.  i need the code to only show the hidden div IF the "SHIP WITH" option is selected.  But again, it still needs to work independently....the other options are for something else.

Comment: So, first of all, when you pass `this` into `ShowDiv`, you're passing a reference to the `HTMLSelectElement`, so you're not going to be able to call `split` on it. Change it to `var name = nameSelect.name;` Once you do that, run `console.log(splitName)`; you'll find it's always `["number","of","skids"]`, since all of your `select`s have the same name. I *think* you want to get the id of the selected `option` and split *that* on the underscore. In that case you'd use `var name = nameSelect.options[nameSelect.selectedIndex].id;`... you're on your own after that; it's Friday night where I'm at.

Comment: @HereticMonkey - Your method worked (  `var name = nameSelect.options[nameSelect.selectedIndex].id;` ) - Can you post as an answer so that I can accept it?  Using that in combination of `name.split('_')`,  I was able to make the comparison and show the correct element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, it looks like you want to get the `id` of the selected `option`, not the `select`. One way of getting that is to use the [`selectedIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedIndex) property of the `select` in combination with its [`options`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionsCollection) collection (you could also use [`selectedOptions[0]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedOptions), among other techniques).

I've taken the liberty of "correcting" some naming conventions; generally, initial uppercase letters denote an object's constructor, not a plain function or variable. Also, using `var` (or `let` or `const`, depending on the need) before a variable assignment keeps it from becoming a global variable by default. There were a few other minor corrections made I'll leave to you to discover.

```js
function showDiv(nameSelect) {

  console.log(nameSelect);
  if (nameSelect) {

    var selectedOption = nameSelect.options[nameSelect.selectedIndex];
    var name = selectedOption.id;
    var splitName = name.split('_');

    console.log(splitName[1]);
    var idOfSection = splitName[0] + '_' + splitName[1];

    var optionValue = selectedOption.value;
    if (optionValue == nameSelect.value) {
      document.getElementById(idOfSection).style.display = "block";
    } else {
      document.getElementById(idOfSection).style.display = "none";
    }
  } else {
    // Commenting this out, since splitName will be undefined in this branch...
    //document.getElementById(splitName[0] + splitName[1]).style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<select name="number_of_skids" onchange="showDiv(this);">
  <option value="SHIP WITH" id="SHIPWITH_11_Show">SHIP WITH</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2" selected="selected">2</option>
</select>

<div id="SHIPWITH_11" style="display: none;">
  <select name="ship_with_product">
    <option value="">SELECT PRODUCT</option>
    <option value="4">1234</option>
  </select>
</div>


<select name="number_of_skids" onchange="showDiv(this);">
  <option value="SHIP WITH" id="SHIPWITH_21_Show">SHIP WITH</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2" selected="selected">2</option>
</select>

<div id="SHIPWITH_21" style="display: none;">
  <select name="ship_with_product">
    <option value="">SELECT PRODUCT</option>
    <option value="4">1234</option>
  </select>
</div>





<select name="number_of_skids" onchange="showDiv(this);">
  <option value="SHIP WITH" id="SHIPWITH_33_Show">SHIP WITH</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2" selected="selected">2</option>
</select>

<div id="SHIPWITH_33" style="display: none;">
  <select name="ship_with_product">
    <option value="">SELECT PRODUCT</option>
    <option value="4">1234</option>
  </select>
</div>
```